# How to create small data integration job in Mule Kernel

Tags: mule, data-integration

I have a few relational databases in Oracle, MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL that need to be integrated into one single PostgreSQL database. This job needs to be run every few hours. Mule Kernel came into my radar as a (free) tool that is capable of data integration. However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to configure Mule Kernel, create integration jobs and run them. I was wondering if there was any documentation or sample to start with?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very open question, but you could start with the [Scheduler documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/scheduler-concept), to trigger the flow at given period of time, then configure one or more [Database connectors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/db-connector-index) to execute the database queries.

For a general overview of Mule see the docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/